# Reading Excel sheet with images

Tags: asp.net, excel, closedxml

I am working on an ASP.NET website where I have to upload an Excel file containing user name, password, email address and user picture. I am able to import data to database (SQL) without image column using ClosedXML library but am unaware of how to read images and save them to DB.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** ClosedXML now supportes images, see [here](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/How-can-I-insert-an-image).

---

**Original Answer:**

You can read the text from the Excel file, but you can't access the image with ClosedXML. The answer below is the same for reading images as for inserting them.

> **How can I insert an image?**
>
> You can't. Although you can open an Excel that already has an image
>   and save it preserving the image, you can't insert a new image with
>   ClosedXML.

[from the official FAQ](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20can%20I%20insert%20an%20image%3F&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score 0):

You need .NET library for Excel able to read/insert images like:

[Working with images - Spreadsheet .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/spreadsheet/tutorial/insertimage.html)